# Selenium headless browser making WhatsApp web ask for update on chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

So I made this bot with selenium on python. While headful(non headless) it works perfectly on Firefox, Chrome and Brave. While headless, it works with Firefox, but on Chrome and Brave its asking me to update chrome. For chrome and brave its using the same webdriver. **Chrome, Brave and the webdriver, all three are version 98.xxx .** I have attached the image I got by capturing a screenshot with `driver.save_screenshot(file)` while headless.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Baasically selenium headless is picking up older version of the chrome browser.
I too encountered this error in my program and I managed to fix this problem by providing the following code

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: I tried what you did and it does not seem to be working for me. Maybe WhatsApp can detect we are using headless?

Comment: For linux: `user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36`